# Не перемещается текст

Tags: html, css

Только начал изучать html и css. Пытаюсь по гайду на ютубе сделать так, чтобы текст был не возле левого края, а ближе к середине. Переписал все в точности, как на видео, но все равно текст у левого края

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      affsd
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Как у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как у него:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

способ 1:

используйте `text-align: justyfy`

способ 2:

используйте `padding-left:` только для этого надо скорректировать ширину или явно (смотри пример) или включив `box-sizing: content-box` чтобы в ширине не учитывался отступ

```css
.center {
  width:      250px;
  height:     30px;
  border:     1px solid black;
  
  text-align: center;
}

.no-center {
  width:      calc(250px - 50px);
  height:     30px;
  border:     1px solid black;
  
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'center'>ТЕКСТ</div>

<br>

<div class = 'no-center'>ТЕКСТ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выровнять по центру можно, добавив блоку с классом container такой стиль:
**text-align: center;**.
Данная строка означает следующее: **выровнять текст внутри блока** с классом container по центру.
Строка **margin: 0 auto;** выставляет отступы **снаружи** (в данном случае справа и слева) **блока** с классом container. Данную команду уместно использовать для выравнивания текста только в том случае, если размер блока, в котором находится текст, соответствует размеру текста. Для изучения можете попробовать (хотя в данном случае размер блока будет не совсем по размеру текста, просто для примера):

```
.container{
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```